# Mavik Thumbnails for Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

Is there a way how to use Mavik Thumbnails plugin on Joomla 3?

Comment: From The Joomla! Extensions Directory - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/articles-images/6263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and it seems that original Mavik Thumbnails are very easy to be rewritten for Joomla 3.

Here is the reult https://github.com/aidik/Mavik-Thumbnails-J3/releases

It is not much tested, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a test version of Mavik Thumbnails 2 from http://www.mavik.com.ua/download/mavikthumbnails_2.zip. This version is compatible with Joomla 3.

Keep in mind that it's still in beta (as far as I understood from the ukranian forums). I have not used it myself, only installed, but it does install without problems in Joomla 3.3.3.